# Using cls file - "the document class provides `book'."

Tags: document-classes

I am co-writing a book and I've been sent the publishers LaTeX template which contains their style files. At first I was getting the error `ietbook.cls file not found` - the following seemed to be the error:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{ietbook}
```

The file name was:

```
`IETBook.cls`
```

After I have changed this to:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{IETBook}
```

I am now getting the following warnings (The compiled file is clearly wrong in format):

```
./IETBook.cls: LaTeX Warning: You have requested document class `IETBook', but the document class provides `book'.
./fleqn.sty: LaTeX Warning: inputting `fleqn.clo' instead of obsolete `fleqn.sty'.
./IETBook.cls:765: Package crop Warning: Requested option `' not provided on input line 765.
```

What could be causing this issue?

EDIT:
Line referred to in third warning:

`\if@cropmarkson \crop[cam,info] \fi`

Comment: They all seem to be errors in the class file provided by the publisher. Complain to them....

Comment: Before I complain is the error regarding `fleqn.sty` ignorable or does it also look like a serious issue?

Comment: It's ignorable as in latex does fix it but fleqn.sty has been obsolete and replaced by fleqn.clo since 1994. They have had time to make the one line change required by now....

Comment: Thanks for your input, hopefully I was just sent an archived template by mistake.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This means that the class file is `IETBook.cls` but has the line

```
\ProvidesClass{book}
```

presumably just copied without thought from the standard book class.

Or possibly it uses

```
\input{book.cls}
```

instead of

```
\LoadClass{book}
```

which would make a similar warning.

As it's a publisher supplied class there is not much you can do other than complain to them and ask that they fix it.

You could of course fix it locally just putting the correct name into the
`\ProvidesClass` line, but generally it's best not to edit publisher supplied classes. It should be fixed at source.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try that tomorrow and accept if it fixes the problem. At least it will give the publisher something to go on if it fixes the problem.

Comment: @Colin747 only addresses the first warning, with the other ones it's a bit harder to guess exactly what is wrong without seeing the code

Comment: I'll add the line the warning is referring too in my original post.